# Dynamically select from multiple lists of valid data based on user input

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm creating a mock up of a user input form and I need to create dynamic/dependent data validation. The logic is quite involved and I've exceeded the 255 character limit on the data validation source field.

Current data validation source field.

```
=IF(OR($B3="",$C3=""),$D$28,IF(AND($B3="Trayline",$C3="38mm"),$D$20:$D$27,IF(AND($B3="Trayline",$C3="25mm"),$D$31:$D$38,IF(AND($B3="Standing Seam",$C3="38mm"),$D$42:$D$49,IF(AND($B3="Standing Seam",$C3="25mm"),$D$53:$D$60,$D$62)))))
```

There must be a better way to do this? I've come across indirect trying to find the answer myself online, but that seems to be focused on creating a dynamic list of valid inputs, not multiple lists that are selected dynamically based on previous inputs.

[current spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dq96N.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
=CHOOSE((A2<>"")*(B2<>"")*((A2="Trayline")*8+(A2="Standing Seam")*4+(B2="38mm")*2+(B2="25mm"))+1,$D$28,"","","",$D$62,$D$53:$D$60,$D$42:$D$49,"",$D$62,$D$31:$D$38,$D$20:$D$27)
```

Comment: no explanation?

Comment: @AlexM I do not see what to explain. Everyone may create some source data and divide the formula for to look the value for each separate condition and each intermediate expression in 1st parameter - he will see the relation between separate conditions, final expression value and values list, and will understand why some values are empty strings. The solution is too local, it is a trick, not a method.